# Is this valid html

Tags: html, internet-explorer, xhtml

```
<a href="/selection"><input type="button" class="big" value="Somewhere"></a>
```

because in IE it doesnt click....any ideas why..all other browsers seem fine

Comment: Have you tried using the w3c validators http://validator.w3.org/ You may need a little more than the snippet you provided but it should be good

Comment: what `doctype` are you using?

Comment: Seems weird to put an anchor around an input. To me, it is either a hyperlink, or a button; but not both.

Comment: Since you tagged this [xhtml] for whatever reason... it's not well-formed XHTML because you didn't self-close the input tag.

Answer (score 9):

It's [invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://jsbin.com/iyuxeb) — an `<input>` cannot be as a descendant of an `<a>` element:

[image: HTML Validator Screenshot]

Source: http://jsbin.com/iyuxeb

Comment: +1 An interesting observation: they changed the rules when authoring HTML5 — this used to be fine in HTML 4.01. I say, it's a good change. It makes completely no sense to have an input in an anchor.

Comment: @rjb - any idea on how to rewrite it to still have the same look and still go the /selection location

Comment: @Tamer: Change `<a href="/selection">...</a>` to `<form action="/selection" method="get">...</form>`. That submits an empty form to `/selection`, and subsequently takes the user there.